# Flutter: Unable to allow input from the user

Tags: dart, flutter

**Normal situation**

[image]

---

**When keyboard opens**

It shows overflow error

[image]

---

**When `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` included**

TextField is hidden beneath keyboard

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // including this hides TextField beneath Keyboard
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlutterLogo(size: 500),
          TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "  Enter something here ...")),
          Expanded(child: FlutterLogo(size: 300)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

What I want is the `TextField` should scroll up automatically when it it is in focus, that also means FlutterLogo1 should scroll up too and FlutterLogo2 should be underneath keyboard. (This is very common behavior in Android natively, everything is handled for you)

Comment: What is  your expected UI ? I guess you want a full screen logo and have text field on it, well for such thing why don't you use stack. and you have given hard coded size i.e 500 in your UI which is not the right thing to do as the possibility of overflow is more in such approach.

Comment: @KalpeshKundanani I have edited the question to add more information about what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that will work.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // including this hides TextField beneath Keyboard
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlutterLogo(size: 500),
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                child: TextField( decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "  Enter something here ..."))),
            Expanded(child: FlutterLogo(size: 300)),
          ],)

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a nice answer, the `TextField` will be shown over the 1st `FlutterLogo`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry I am not looking for a workaround to use `Stack`.